# Things to check after a untrusted USB device was mounted

Tags: linux, security, usb

Suppose you plugged an untrusted usb-stick into your linux machine (as user) and browsed and copied some files, perhaps using a graphical interface.

After the usb-stick is removed (and not available to you anymore), what are the things you would check (for example specific log files) to see, if the stick did some malicious on my system.

Clearly this would not detect  all possible attaks and clearly the best idea is simply not to conncect the stick to your pc, but what would be the best thing to do in this case (except of reinstalling the  system)?

Comment: Without reinstalling, you can only analyse your system very carefully (best by booting a read-only live system). See e.g. http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7443/how-do-you-know-your-server-has-been-compromised for some things to check.

Answer (score 2):

There is no thing as default autostart from a removable device in the DEs I know. So the only malicious code executed would bugs in the filesystem (unlikely) and bugs in the applications used to open the files.
I would search for known security problems in the programs used (like LibreOffice etc). Where to find these depends on the program and the distribution.

Another idea, provided you only used the stick and opened the files only with user permissions and not root, I would copy all files with root which only are payload (like documents, pictures, music etc.) to another location, empty the home directory, copy /etc/skel/* to it, move the saved data back and start again with a "clean" home directory.

Being kind of paranoid about security is not totally wrong but realisticaly an updated linux installation should be fine, when no binaries/scripts from the stick where run.

As jofel pointed out, there could be a problem with a malicious firmware on the stick. You should see, whether there are any hints in syslog (and dmesg? not sure) for connected usb devices other than usb drives.

Now, there is a possibility that the drive installed a keylogger or a malicious su/sudo and you wanted to get root access in your DE (entered your root password from a user environment) and your logs were altered. When the device had a chance to get root permission, there's no other way as reinstalling to be safe.

Comment: At least in theory, a USB stick could emulate first a keyboard or any other USB device to compromise the system, before appearing as an regular storage device with normal files. Therefore analysing opened files is not enough (but of course better than nothing).

Comment: You are right, forgot that.

Comment: Strictly speaking, reinstalling isn't enough: if the trojan got root access, it might have implanted itself in some firmware (BIOS, hard disk, network controller, …), in which case you'd need to chuck the hardware. Fortunately such trojans aren't yet common in the wild (but if you're worried about government-level attackers you'd need to worry about that).